# Failed to read data from a hadoop URL

Tags: hadoop

I am following Tom White's 'Hadoop - The Definitive Guide'. 
When I try to use the Java Interface to read data from a hadoop URL I get the following error message:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop URLCat hdfs://master/hdfs/data/SampleText.txt
12/11/21 13:46:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/11/21 13:46:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/11/21 13:46:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/11/21 13:46:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/11/21 13:46:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/11/21 13:46:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.9.55:8020. Already tried 5 time(s).
```

The Contents of the URLCat file are as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory;

public class URLCat {
static {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
}
}
```

The /etc/hosts file contents are:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.ubuntu-domain    ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# /ect/hosts Master and slaves
192.168.9.55    master
192.168.9.56    slave1
192.168.9.57    slave2
192.168.9.58    slave3
```

Comment: Please provide some more information: what Hadoop daemons are running (check it with jps), what is the value of `fs.default.name` in core-site.xml ?

Comment: The value of `fs.default.name` is `hdfs://master:54310`. Adding the `:54310` makes it function correctly. 
Can you elaborate on what exactly is it that I did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd check whether the Hadoop daemons are running. A convenient tool is [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) . Make sure that (at least) the namenode and the datanodes are running.

If you still can't connect, check whether the url is correct. As you provided *hdfs://master/* (without any port number) Hadoop assumes that your namenode listens on port **8020** (default). This is what you see in the logs.

For a quick lookup in `core-site.xml` (*fs.default.name*) you can check whether you have a custom port defined for the filesystem URI (in this case 54310).